# High Xorg usage

Tags: xorg, lightdm

I was wondering if someone could help me find out why Xorg is using so much cpu %

```
 2952 root      20   0  389856 107076  36660 R  80.1  0.7  12:15.60 Xorg
 3995 ntuser    20   0 1618300 223672  74952 S   4.0  1.4   0:51.77 compiz
 3418 ntuser    20   0  371068 257608  15500 R   3.0  1.6   0:56.53 TeamViewer_Desk
 3420 ntuser    20   0 2669576  50688  17140 S   0.3  0.3   0:08.13 TeamViewer.exe
 3749 ntuser    20   0  517668  28424  22516 S   0.3  0.2   0:00.55 bamfdaemon
 3836 ntuser    20   0    6352   3428   1888 S   0.3  0.0   0:05.57 wineserver
 4031 ntuser    20   0 1097416  52808  40600 S   0.3  0.3   0:00.72 nautilus
    1 root      20   0  119824   5996   4000 S   0.0  0.0   0:12.48 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.08 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   0.0  0.0   0:05.09 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/0
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/1
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.09 ksoftirqd/1
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
   17 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
   18 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 perf
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 writeback
   21 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd
   22 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.16 khugepaged
   23 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto
   24 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
   25 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
   26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
   27 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff
   28 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md
   29 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 devfreq_wq
```

It seems to idle around 2% but as soon as i interact with the desktop it shoots back up.

I have already disabled 'Sync to VBlank' in OpenGL

Appreciate any pointers here.

Comment: No hardware acceleration?

Comment: How do I make sure it's disabled?

Comment: You want it to be _enabled_. To check, use `glxinfo` (install it with `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`) or `inxi` (install it with `sudo apt-get install inxi`). For example, `inxi -v3` should say `Direct Rendering: yes` under Graphics.

Comment: @AlexP So it looks like it's enabled


`Card: Matrox Systems MGA G200eW WPCM450 bus-ID: 02:03.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: mga (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1280x1024@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes`

Comment: You have a [Matrox G200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrox_G200), a graphics card first released in 1998 -- or at least, this is what the system believes that you have. You may want to try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.me/), an Ubuntu flavor specifically designed for less powerful hardware.

Comment: the only issue i have is that the GUI need to be able to use team viewer before logging in, do you know if Lubuntu supports this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving to XFCE give me a massive improvement!